# GetRelatedEntities<T> empty list (no records for the parent) vs null (the records have not yet been set)

Tags: servicestack, servicestack.redis

I am using the Redis Store and GetRelatedEntities calls to associate a userId with groups for that user.

In the service call I want to see if the groups have ever been stored in to the cache yet before I invoke the expensive database call to get the groups for the first time (I assume this is pretty standard)

The GetRelatedEntities call returns an empty List if the StoreRelatedEntities has not been called before for that userId.  However, an empty list can have the meaning of the user not having any groups, so I need a way to establish that the groups have not been set for that user before.

Is there any way I can distinguish between the two states?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anyway to distinguish between an empty collection in Redis and one that does not exist since Redis automatically deletes a collection whenever it doesn't have any elements and the behavior of querying a collection that doesn't exist or is empty is the same, i.e. it returns an empty collection.

I'd recommend maintaining a custom Set of userIds that have caches whenever calling StoreRelatedEntities, e.g:

```
redis.AddItemToSet("userGroupsCache", user.Id);
redis.As<User>().StoreRelatedEntites(user.Id, groups);
```

Then you can query the set whether it's been cached or not, e.g:

```
var userCacheExists = redis.SetContainsItem("userGroupsCache", user.Id);
```